# $lookup not returning empty array mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, mongoose

I am creating mongodb with aggregate in which it should join two table so I have used $lookup but query returning me empty array
here is my query

```
return userScoringModel.aggregate([
        {
            "$match": {
                examId: new ObjectId(req.params.examId),
                user_Id: new ObjectId(req.params.userId),
                subject: subject,
                correctMark: {$lt: 0}
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "examPortalQuestions",
                localField: "questionId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "question_text"
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {chapter: '$chapter'},
                "questionNumbers": {$push: "$questionNo"},
                "question_text": {$push: '$question_text'}
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "subject": {
                    "name": "$_id.subject",
                    "chapter": "$_id.chapter",
                    "questionNumber": "$questionNumbers",
                    "question": "$question_text"
                }
            }
        }
    ]).exec()
```

and here is output

```
{
    "subject": {
        "chapter": "NUMBER TEST AND PAIR FINDING",
        "questionNumber": [
            "20"
        ],
        "question": [
            []
        ]
    }
},
```

sample collection
**score table**:

```
_id,      examid,   userid ,   questionId,                    chapter
objectId  ObjectId  ObjectId   ObjectId (ref:'questiontable') XYZ
objectId  ObjectId  ObjectId   ObjectId (ref:'questiontable') qwe
```

**Question table** :

```
_id,       question,
ObjectId   what is abc?
```

here I am getting question array empty 
can someone suggest me how to archive it
thanks in advance

Comment: I have updated question with sample collection

Comment: I want your exact sample collection... Copy it from mongo shell or robomongo